# Remove unique elements from a 2d array and return the repeating element

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to remove unique elements from a 2d array and return the repeating elements.
For Ex:

```
let arr = [ [ 'Alexandra', 'Female', 'Senior', 'CA', 'English', 'Drama Club' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Benjamin', 'Male', 'Senior', 'WI', 'English', 'Basketball' ],
  [ 'Carl', 'Male', 'Junior', 'MD', 'Art', 'Debate' ]]
```

Output should be:

```
[[ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ]]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what challenge are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be something like this:

```js
let arr = [ [ 'Alexandra', 'Female', 'Senior', 'CA', 'English', 'Drama Club' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Benjamin', 'Male', 'Senior', 'WI', 'English', 'Basketball' ],
  [ 'Carl', 'Male', 'Junior', 'MD', 'Art', 'Debate' ]
]

const get_not_uniq_elements = arr => arr.filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) !== arr.lastIndexOf(x));
const flatt_2d_array = arr => arr.map(x => x.join('\t'));
const unflat_array = arr => arr.map(x => x.split('\t'));

var new_arr = flatt_2d_array(arr);
new_arr = get_not_uniq_elements(new_arr);
new_arr = unflat_array(new_arr);

console.log(new_arr);
```

Or the same algorithm in one line:

```
let new_arr = arr.map(x => x.join('\t'))
  .filter((x,_,a) => a.indexOf(x) !== a.lastIndexOf(x))
  .map(x => x.split('\t'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as in the demo below.

```js
const arr = [ [ 'Alexandra', 'Female', 'Senior', 'CA', 'English', 'Drama Club' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Andrew', 'Male', 'Freshman', 'SD', 'Math', 'Lacrosse' ],
  [ 'Benjamin', 'Male', 'Senior', 'WI', 'English', 'Basketball' ],
  [ 'Carl', 'Male', 'Junior', 'MD', 'Art', 'Debate' ]],
      
      output = arr.filter(
          ([firstName,gender,classOf,state,course,club],i,a) => 
          a.find(
              ([fn,g,co,st,cs,cb],j) =>
              i !== j && fn === firstName &&
                         g  === gender &&
                         co === classOf && 
                         st === state &&
                         cs === course &&
                         cb === club
          )
      );
       
console.log( output );
```